# Inversify's dependency injection like angular's using TS decorators

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, decorator, inversifyjs

Today I switched a js *electron* project to typescript, asking myself if there is an equivalence to *angular*'s dependency injection. As *Angular Universal* seems to be at a very early state and there is no documentation at all in using it with electron instead of *express*, it seems that *inversify* could fit my needs. Also because it's more lightweight than angular, as I only need DI.

I ended up in trying to create a decorator that should work similar to `NgModule` decorator in Angular.

```js
import { app, Menu, ipcMain, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';
import { Container } from 'inversify';
import { DatabaseService } from 'core/database.service';

function servermodule(data: {providers: Array<any>}) {
  // Some code that instantiate the declarations array classes
  // Do they have to be returned, if I don't need a reference?

  let container = new Container();
  return (target: Object) => {
    for(const service of data.providers) {
      container.bind(service).toSelf();
    }
  }

}
```

which cycles through each entry in providers and binds it to inversifys container object. This function I want to use as follows. The usage would then be exactly as in angulars decorator.

```js
@servermodule({
  declarations: [
    // Some other classes, that maybe can get DatabaseService injected
  ],
  providers: [
    DatabaseService
  ]
})
export class AppModule { ...
```

The `DatabaseService` could for example look like

```js
 import { injectable } from 'inversify';

 @injectable()
 export class DatabaseService { ...
```

And should be injectable in angular style, e.g. like

```js
import { inject } from 'inversify';
import { DatabaseService } from './database.service';

export class Models {
  constructor(@inject(DatabaseService) dbService: DatabaseService) { }
}
```

I'm not sure about inversify's container. Is its scope only in the decorator function? Would it be better to use it as

```
container = new Container({ autoBindInjectable: true });
```

How do I return it properly to the `AppModule`? Is my idea to declare the classes in servermodule decorator a good thought?

For now I just get the following error message on tsc and electron execution, but there are no ts linting errors.

```
App threw an error during load
Error: Cannot find module 'database.service'
```

Another idea/question is: If I want in addition to declarations and providers an import attribute. Would it then be a good idea to modify the constructor by the decorator and import these classes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding this question half a year ago, I worked on implementing decorator functions for an hierarchical DI that look similar to the angular ones and bundled them in an [npm package fl-node-di](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fl-node-di). With it you are able to generate *modules*

```js
FlModule({
  imports: [ AnotherModule ] // imports other FlModules
  providers: [ MyService ] // adds Injectables() to the modules container
  declaration: [] // same as providers but immediatly creates an instance
  exports: [] // places the Injectable() in the parents container
})
export class MyModule {}
```

The other module could look like

```js
FlModule({
  declarations: [ MyComponent ]
})
export class AnotherModule {}
```

And the component could look like

```
@Component()
export class MyComponent {
  constructor (@Inject(MyService) myService: MyService) {}
}
```

Pay attention to the Service. The service is provided in the parent module, so this is hierarchical.